# Terminology capturing ordering characteristic of arguments in functional composition

Tags: functional-programming, terminology, function-composition

In functional composition `g compose f` what terms are used to refer to and differentiate the *ordering* property of functional arguments `f` and `g` passed to composition operator `compose`? For example, given the following compositions

```
val reverse = (s: String) => s.reverse
val dropThree = (s: String) => s.drop(3)

(reverse compose dropThree)("Make it so!") // ==> !os ti e: java.lang.String
(dropThree compose reverse)("Make it so!") // ==> ti ekaM: java.lang.String
```

what terminology makes explicit `reverse` comes **after** in

```
reverse compose dropThree
```

whilst it comes **first** in

```
dropThree compose reverse
```

Over at [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2847689/305915) they seem to think such precise terminology has not yet emerged

> ...I'd aim for an analogy with division or subtraction: you might, for
>   instance, call the outer function the **composer** and the inner the
>   **composand**. Words like this are not (as far as I know) in common use,
>   perhaps because the need for them hasn't arisen as often as those for
>   the elementary arithmetic operations.

however, in software engineering world, composition, chaining, pipelining, etc. seems ubiquitous, and is bread-and-butter of functional programming, thus there ought to exist precise terminology characterising the crucial ordering property of operands involved in composition.

Note the terms the question is after refer specifically to particular arguments of composition, not the whole expression, akin to *divisor* and *dividend* which precisely describe which is which in division.

Comment: `reverse compose dropThree` is Scala, and equivalent to `reverse.compose(dropThree)`, right?

Comment: Yes, in Scala punctation may be dropped in [infix notation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#infix-notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any formal terminology, but I would express `a ∘ b` (`λx.a(b(x))`) as

- composition of `a` and `b`
- `a` composed with `b`
- `a` composed onto `b`
- `a` chained onto `b`
- `a` after `b`
- `b` before `a`
- `x` pipelined through `b` and `a`

As for the designations of the arguments to the `compose` function, I guess you're left with the Math.SE answer.

Comment: Ideally, the terms question is after should refer specifically to particular arguments, akin to `divisor` and `dividend` which precisely describe which is which in division.

Comment: Ah, ok, I don't know any terms for those. *composer* and *composand* are probably the only you will get.